# How to prevent python program crash when receiving alphabetical characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, crash, integer

My code is working just the way I want - unless input contains alphabetical characters. If so, is crashes. How can I prevent that? My code is as follows:

```py
def main():
    
    choice ='0'

    while choice =='0':
        print ("-" * 30 + "MENU" + "-" * 30)
        print ("|" + " " * 19 + "1. Hourly to annual pay" + " " * 20 + "|")
        print ("|" + " " * 19 + "2. Annual to hourly pay" + " " * 20 + "|")
        print ("|" + " " * 19 + "3. Exit" + " " * 36 + "|")
        print ("-" * 64)
    
        choice = input ("Choose an option 1-3: ")
        if choice =="1":
            hourly = input ("Enter hourly pay: ")
            annual = float (hourly) * 2080
            print ("Annual pay is: ")
            print ("{:0.2f}".format(annual))
            main()
        elif choice =="2":
            a = input ("Enter annual pay: ")
            h = float (a) / 2080
            x = round(h, 2)
            print ("{:0.2f}".format(x))
            main()
        elif choice =="3":
            print ("Program exited gracefully.")
            raise SystemExit(0)
        else:
            print ("Unrecognized command - choose 1-3")
           
        
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can catch ValueError when trying to convert the input to a float value. I modified your code to show how it could be done:

```py
def get_float_input(prompt: str) -> float:
    try:
        data = input(prompt)
        data = float(data)

        return data
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError('Please enter a valid number')


def main():
    while True:
        print("-" * 30 + "MENU" + "-" * 30)
        print("|" + " " * 19 + "1. Hourly to annual pay" + " " * 20 + "|")
        print("|" + " " * 19 + "2. Annual to hourly pay" + " " * 20 + "|")
        print("|" + " " * 19 + "3. Exit" + " " * 36 + "|")
        print("-" * 64)

        choice = input("Choose an option 1-3: ")
        if choice == "1":
            try:
                hourly = get_float_input("Enter hourly pay: ")
            except ValueError as e:
                print(e)
                continue

            annual = hourly * 2080
            print("Annual pay is: ")
            print("{:0.2f}".format(annual))

        elif choice == "2":
            try:
                a = get_float_input("Enter annual pay: ")
            except ValueError as e:
                print(e)
                continue

            h = a / 2080
            x = round(h, 2)
            print("{:0.2f}".format(x))

        elif choice == "3":
            print("Program exited gracefully.")
            raise SystemExit(0)

        else:
            print("Unrecognized command - choose 1-3")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `while True` to run program until user enters 3(infinite loop). Inorder to handle this problem you can use try except statement.
So, your code needs to be like this

```
def main():
    
    print ("-" * 30 + "MENU" + "-" * 30)
    print ("|" + " " * 19 + "1. Hourly to annual pay" + " " * 20 + "|")
    print ("|" + " " * 19 + "2. Annual to hourly pay" + " " * 20 + "|")
    print ("|" + " " * 19 + "3. Exit" + " " * 36 + "|")
    print ("-" * 64)
    try:
        while True:
                choice = input ("Choose an option 1-3: ")
                if choice =="1":
                    hourly = input ("Enter hourly pay: ")
                    annual = float (hourly) * 2080
                    print ("Annual pay is: ")
                    print ("{:0.2f}".format(annual))
        
                elif choice =="2":
                    a = input ("Enter annual pay: ")
                    h = float (a) / 2080
                    x = round(h, 2)
                    print ("{:0.2f}".format(x))
        
                elif choice =="3":
                    print ("Program exited gracefully.")
                    raise SystemExit(0)
    except ValueError:
        print ("Unrecognized command - choose 1-3")
        
    
main()
```

Comment: I got it going - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best thing you can do is to use exception handling while converting the input data to float. It will catch all invalid inputs that cant be converted to float.

```
def main():

    choice ='0'

    while choice =='0':
        print ("-" * 30 + "MENU" + "-" * 30)
        print ("|" + " " * 19 + "1. Hourly to annual pay" + " " * 20 + "|")
        print ("|" + " " * 19 + "2. Annual to hourly pay" + " " * 20 + "|")
        print ("|" + " " * 19 + "3. Exit" + " " * 36 + "|")
        print ("-" * 64)

        choice = input ("Choose an option 1-3: ")
        if choice =="1":
            hourly = input ("Enter hourly pay: ")
            try:
                annual = float (hourly) * 2080
                print ("Annual pay is: ")
                print ("{:0.2f}".format(annual))
            except:
                print("Invalid Input")
            main()
        elif choice =="2":
            a = input ("Enter annual pay: ")
            try:
                h = float (a) / 2080
                x = round(h, 2)
                print ("{:0.2f}".format(x))
            except:
                print("Invalid Input")
            main()
        elif choice =="3":
            print ("Program exited gracefully.")
            raise SystemExit(0)
        else:
            print ("Unrecognized command - choose 1-3")
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a handy helper whenever I want numerical input.

```
def get_num(prompt="Enter number: "):
    """
    (str) -> num
    Outputs a prompt and loops until a valid number is
    entered by the user, at which point that value is
    returned and the function terminates
    """
    while True:
        num = input(prompt)
        try:
            num = float(num)
            return num
        except:
            print("Must enter a valid number")
            

def main():
    
    while True:
        print ("-" * 30 + "MENU" + "-" * 30)
        print ("|" + " " * 19 + "1. Hourly to annual pay" + " " * 20 + "|")
        print ("|" + " " * 19 + "2. Annual to hourly pay" + " " * 20 + "|")
        print ("|" + " " * 19 + "3. Exit" + " " * 36 + "|")
        print ("-" * 64)
    
        choice = get_num("Choose an option 1-3: ")
        if choice == 1:
            hourly = get_num("Enter hourly pay: ")
            annual = hourly * 2080
            print ("Annual pay is: ")
            print ("{:0.2f}".format(annual))
            # main() recursive call- don't do this
        elif choice == 2:
            a = get_num("Enter annual pay: ")
            h = a / 2080
            x = round(h, 2)
            print ("{:0.2f}".format(x))
            main()
        elif choice == 3:
            print ("Program exited gracefully.")
            raise SystemExit(0)
        else:
            print ("Unrecognized command - choose 1-3")
        repeat = input("Enter Y to repeat or any other key to quit: ")
        if repeat.lower() != "y":
            break
           
        
main()
```